# Storing Unselected users from a checkbox list (initial checked) to an array -

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array (*checkeduserslist*) which contains pairs of userid and username values. It is displayed as the image below[image]

My requirement is that when i unselect a check box , those value is to be stored in another array, say "*unselectedUsersList*"

Below is a dummy funnction that im trying to implement.

```
    unselectExistingUser(usr: any, event: any) {
    if (event.target.checked == false) {
        this.unselectedUsersList.push(usr);
    }
    else if (event.target.checked) {
        var indx = this.unselectedUsersList.findIndex(usr);
        this.unselectedUsersList.splice(indx, 1);
    }
    console.log('unselected users :', this.unselectedUsersList);
}
```

The argument `usr` contains the userid/password values that is to be inserted or deleted. Insertion is taking place in this, but no idea how to spice the value of when checked. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different path. Instead of using two arrays I would use one single array and a flag `isSelected`:

```
interface User {
    id: number;
}

interface SelectableUser extends User {
    isSelected: boolean;
}


class Something {
    users: SelectableUser[];
    unselectExistingUser(usr: SelectableUser, event: any) {
        this.users.map((currentUser) => {
            if (usr.id === currentUser.id) {
                currentUser.isSelected = event.target.checked; 
            }
            return currentUser;
        });;
    }
}
```